# About the continuity of a function between topological spaces

Tags: general-topology, continuity

Let $X$, $Y$ and $Z$ be three topological spaces, let $g : X \times Y \to Z$ be a continuous function and let $f : X \to Z$ be a function such that $f(x) = g(x , y_0)$ for some $y_0 \in Y$ for all $x \in X$. I would like to know if $f$ is also continuous.

My attempt has been the next: let $x_0$ be a point in $X$ and let $W$ be a open neighborhood of $f(x_0)$ in $Z$. As $g(x_0 , y_0) = f(x_0)$ and $g$ is continuous, there exists a open neighborhood $U$ of $(x_0 , y_0)$ in $X \times Y$ such that $g(U) \subset W$. But what can I do now? Does it imply that there exists other open neighborhood $V$ of $x_0$ in $X$ such that $f(V) \subset W$? Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the map$$\begin{array}{rccc}\pi\colon&X\times Y&\longrightarrow&X\\&(x,y)&\mapsto&x.\end{array}$$It is a continuous map. And now consider$$\begin{array}{rccc}\eta\colon&X&\longrightarrow&X\times Y\\&x&\mapsto&(x,y_0),\end{array}$$which is also continuous. Then $f$ is continuous, since $f=g\circ\eta\circ\pi$.

Comment: How can I show that $\eta$ is also continuous?

Comment: If $A$ is an open subset of $X\times Y$, them it can be written as an union $\bigcup_{i\in\Lambda}U_i\times V_i$, where each $U_i$ as an open subset of $X$ and each $V_i$ is an open subset of $Y$. Then$$\eta^{-1}(A)=\bigcup\{U_i\mid i\in\Lambda\text{ and }y_0\in V_i\},$$which is an open subset of $X$.

Comment: I understand, thank you very much.